# Wrong prediction with SVC classifier in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I generated my own corpus, so I split into a training text file like this:

```
POS|This film was awesome, highly recommended
NEG|I did not like this film
NEU|I went to the movies
POS|this film is very interesting, i liked a lot
NEG|the film was very boring i did not like it
NEU|the cinema is big
NEU|the cinema was dark
```

And for testing I have another text review, which is unlabeled:

```
I did not like this film
```

Then I do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer

trainingdata = pd.read_csv('/Users/user/Desktop/training.txt',
                 header=None, sep='|', names=['labels', 'movies_reviews'])


vect = HashingVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(2,2), lowercase=True, n_features=7)
X = vect.fit_transform(trainingdata['movies_reviews'])
y = trainingdata['labels']
TestText= pd.read_csv('/Users/user/Desktop/testing.txt',
                     header=None, names=['test_opinions'])
test = vect.transform(TestText['test_opinions'])
from sklearn.svm import SVC
svm = SVC()
svm.fit(X, y)

prediction = svm.predict(test)
print prediction
```

And the prediction is:

```
['NEU']
```

Then something that comes to my mind is why this prediction is wrong?. Does this is a code problem or a feature or a classification algorithm problem?, I tried to play with this and when I remove the last review from the training text file I realize that always is predicting the last element of that file. Any idea of how to fix this problem?.

Answer (score 1):

SVMs are notoriously sensitive to parameter settings. You will need to do a grid search to find the right values. I tried training two kinds of Naive Bayes on your dataset and I got perfect accuracy on the training set:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import *
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import *

# first option- Gaussian NB
vect = HashingVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(2,2), lowercase=True)
X = vect.fit_transform(trainingdata['movies_reviews'])
y = trainingdata['labels']
nb = GaussianNB().fit(X.A,y) # input needs to be dense
nb.predict(X.A) == y

# second option- MultinomialNB (input needs to be positive, use CountingVect instead)
vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(2,2), lowercase=True)
X = vect.fit_transform(trainingdata['movies_reviews'])
y = trainingdata['labels']
nb = MultinomialNB().fit(X,y)
nb.predict(X.A) == y
```

In both cases the output is

```
Out[33]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
Name: labels, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, do you mean something like this: `from sklearn import grid_search
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10]}
svm = SVC()
clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(svm, testing_matrix)
clf.fit(training_matrix, labels)` ?

Comment: Yes, but you also need to pass the parameter grid into the constructor of `GridSearch`. Also, search a wider interval for C, e.g. from 10^-5 to 10^5 instead of just [1, 10]